# Unitary irreducible representation of $SO(2,2)$

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I would like to study the unitary irreducible representations of the Lorentz group $SO(2,2)$, isomorphic to the conformal group in $(1+1)-$dim. I know one could use the highest weight repn theory to build the repns, but this group is non-compact, and the double cover of this group is $SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, which leads me to nowhere.

If someone could educate me a little, or direct me to relevant literature for me to compute it on my own, that'll be appreciated hugely.

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SL2(R)#Unitary_representations).

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the link. Could you also direct me towards computing the UIR of SO(2,2) using these? Appreciate the help.

Comment: See section 4.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0001053v3, and the references cited there

Comment: @ElliotSchneider This looks helpful. Thanks a lot!